# Error coming on building android fabric project

Tags: android, crashlytics, shim, google-fabric

I just started facing issue while building android project:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/crashlytics/android/answers/shim/R.class

Tried other related answers like cleaning project from terminal, rebuilding but nothing worked.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question itself. As for now, the pastebin link is dead and the question is completely useless. To all the upvoters: How can you upvote a question that so obvious validates the SO policy?

Comment: FYI This question is currently [discussed on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348078/812149). Which probably explains the sudden downvotes.

Comment: @BDL, The question I asked does not seem to be off topic, it is clearly asked and answered as well. Doubt what makes you think that after a long time.

Comment: Your question is off-topic of exactly the reason explained in the message: You must include all relevant information **in the question itself**. Now that the linked document is gone, the question is basically unsolvable. There is also no way to know for another visitor whether he has the same problem or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try replacing

```
compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
```

With

```
compile ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
exclude module: 'answers-shim' 
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @mario, it was frustrating before you answered!

Comment: I had imported the 'io.branch.invite.sdk.android:library:0.1.+' too, and the error still persisted. I deleted this library cause I didn't use it and works ok. Thank you @mario!.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm.